# Objects penetrate even in bullet mode

Tags: c++, box2d, collision-detection, physics

I have two circle-shaped dynamic bodies in Box2D, both by calling this routine:

```
Disk *World::AddDisk(float32 x, float32 y, float32 radius, float32 density) {
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(x, y);
    bodyDef.bullet = true;
    b2Body *body = this->world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2CircleShape shape;
    shape.m_p.Set(0, 0);
    shape.m_radius = radius;

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
    fixtureDef.density = density;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8;
    b2Fixture *fixture = body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    Disk *d = new Disk(this, body, fixture);
    this->disks.push_back(d);
    return d;
}
```

These are the calls that create my two circles:

```
world.AddDisk(0, 0, 10, 5.97219e+12);
world.AddDisk(20, 20, 5, 1);
```

I tried moving one against the smaller disk against the bigger one by applying a certain force to one while gravity was zero. The circles penetrated a noticeable amount (not too small though).

I also tried using normal gravity, scaling the bigger circle's gravity to zero. The other moved normally, but then it was again repulsed after a small penetration.

Isn't bullet mode (that is, CCD) supposed to eliminate penetration? At first I thought the reason the circles penetrate is that I'm applying a constant force to one, without accounting for normal force when they touch. But then I saw that Box2D's gravity does the same too. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCD is meant to eliminate tunneling, not interpenetration. It specifically eliminates tunneling when a dynamic body collides with a static body. It doesn't work the same with two dynamic bodies.

Every game physics engine I've seen suffers from interpenetration, especially when the bodies have vastly different masses. A good rule of thumb to avoid this is to keep the mass ratio of the bodies less than 10:1 (of course if the Box2D manual suggests a different ratio then go with that). Lowering your time-step could also help.

Comment: I changed the masses so that they are close; no noticeable change. Also made the bigger disk a static body; still the same. Anyway, I thought the sizes needed to be close, not the masses. I want to simulate some inter-planetary physics. Are you saying I'd better roll my own? (I sorta rolled my own, partially, at the beginning, then I thought I'd use Box2D.)

Comment: I guess it could be the constant force like you initially suspected. You'll run into the same problem if you roll your own... of course it could be a fun one to solve.

Comment: I'm actually skeptical of that conslusion now, because Box2D's normal gravity must be the same too --it applies a certain force to the smaller disk (the bigger one being scaled to zero).

Comment: Bodies will almost always penetrate, since they need to before a collision can be resolved. CCD is supposed to stop (usually) small objects that are moving very fast from passing right through something they should hit, eg. a ball hitting a thin wall. If the ball was to stop without actually colliding with the wall, the question of how it should bounce/react is unknown.

Comment: hi, you mean 1 = character and 10 = wall, is this right?